# How to gather values of multiple JS-generated input fields?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a form in which I have an add button. When the add button is clicked a new text box appears where user can enter some data. The user can click add button any number of times. I am using javascript to dynamically generate textboxes. I can maintain a count of the number of textboxes generated. All the values entered in these text boxes have to be stored in database using JSP. How can I store those values in the database as I do not know how many textboxes were created?

Comment: `QuestionNotFoundException`. Please edit your question to add a concrete question :) It starts with "How", "What", "Why", "Where", etc and ends with "?".

Comment: @Hello71: the last sentence was initially not present and the title was awful. The OP added the concrete question after my comment and I finally fixed the title. See also edit history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign the text box count (increment an integer every time they click the Add button) to a hidden input field in the form, then retrieve the value of that field in the JSP when the form is posted.

If you give each new text box a new name, e.g. text{count}, then in your JSP just get the parameters from text0 to text{maxCount}, where maxCount is the count from the hidden field.

Comment: You could even assign the same name to every text area, and simply use request.getParameterValues to get an array of the values entered in the areas. This way, you don't even need a hidden field